# How can I disable journal updates every time a user logs in to my Drupal site?

Tags: php, drupal, filemaker, journal

I have a drupal site in which users can log in and purchase things. However, there is a problem. My site is adding an updateed journal entry for a user account whenever a user logs in. This creates an excess of journal entries that aren't necessary. What can I do to stop this behavior and disable these journal entries when a user logs in?

I just don't know where to start other than to search my whole directory for "journal". I'm seeing some mentions to it in my custom filemaker modules but I don't know php very well and I'm not sure how to properly identify the code that is causing this.

I was wondering if someone had faced a similar issue and if there was a more direct way to go about this and, if not, how would someone who understands how Drupal sites work go about solving this issue and tracking down the code that is causing this to happen?

Comment: Sounds like you have something like https://www.drupal.org/project/journal enabled?